# Translate some text in java

Tags: java, spring, google-translate, translate, farsi

I have a project in java Spring that gets a subtitle file and translates its sentences to Persian.
Now I need some dependency for translating these sentences.
Note that I'm living in Iran and we can not use google translate API.
So I need a free dependency.

Comment: Man, that is tough. I have only used Google Translate. I found this link listing the [Best Free Online Translators](https://www.maketecheasier.com/best-free-online-translators/). I hope that helps you.